How to disable online rule preview in Visual Studio's rule set editor?
Visual Studio once asked me with a small pop-up if I wanted to display rule descriptions from online resources when I opened a rule editor (most commonly used for StyleCop .ruleset files). Foolish me accepted, and now my dark theme is blasted with whiteness across half of my screen space. If this feature would be of any use, then it would make up for itself just a little bit, but no. In most cases, it's just redundant and sometimes does not find anything and returns some generic error message.
I tried to lower the section delimiter horizontal bar by dragging it into the very bottom, hoping it's going to stay like that. Not this time, it resets itself with the next click on a different rule. It's very annoying, especially during night coding sessions.
How can I disable it? I failed to find a corresponding setting for the rule set editor that would disable online rule preview or "description fetching"?


Does this help? https://devcodef1.com/news/1444201/disable-online-rule-previews-in-vs

@stuartd Looks promising, but after I failed to find any of the settings mentioned in the article, it got me wondering. I looked deeper at the site. The article was written only yesterday, the same day I posted, and its title is almost a 1:1 copy of my question title. Quite the coincidence, I'd say. Finally, to eliminate any doubts about what we are dealing with, the site has 18040 pages (sic!) full of articles, so I guess it's just an abyss full of AI hallucinations. AI is rampant, I'm afraid. EDIT: Also, I've just checked how it looks like without AdBlock and... oh my :D

Sorry @Prolog I didn't notice the date.. ugh

@stuartd Not a problem. That was an important lesson for me.
